# AngularJS compare dates wrong

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class, date, if-statement

I just wrote this code.
It should mark the rows that their dates column has in the past.

This is the code:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="row in records | orderBy: sortType : sortReverse" ng-class="{past_date:(date | date:'y M d') > (row.oddate | date:'y M d')}">
            <td>{{ $index +1 }}</td>
            <td>{{row.pname + " " + row.sname}}</td>
            <td>{{row.areaname}}</td>
            <td>{{row.oddate}}</td>
            <td>{{row.odtime}}</td>
            <td>{{row.cnt}}</td>
        </tr>
```

my app has:

```
$scope.date = $filter('date')(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');//new Date();
```

every thing works just fine (the past rows was marked) but some other rows marked too! (before 05/06/2017 marked - Good, 06/06/2017 - 08/06/2017 not marked - Good, 11/06/2017-29/06/2017 marked - Problem!, 02/07/2017 and above not marked - Good).

I check and the all of the dates are fine.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2574/)

What can be the problem??

Thanks!

Comment: Please create a plunker/fiddle/snippet replicating the issue.

Comment: AngularJS compare dates correctly .I think the problem is somewhere else ..its working fine here https://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11493/ .. you can change `$scope.date2` and verify

Comment: @Sajal https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2572/

Comment: It's in Hebrew, I used the original data on purpose.

Comment: @talentedandrew  jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue happens because of string compare "5" > "11"

You are casting dates to `y M d`, so "2017 5 1" will be evaluated to be greater than "2017 11 1"

Solution: use zero padding format `yMMdd`

Comment: Thanks! helped a lot